# Player with 350 or more goals in domestic league

Tags: football

When Messi passed 350 goals for Barcelona, I asked this question, but couldn't find an answer anywhere. Who has scored more goals than Messi for a single club?

Edit: I was specifically asking for the goals in the domestic league.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Josef Bican 534 with Slavia Prague
- Pelé 643 with Santos
- Ferenc Puskás 387 with Budapest Honved
- Gerd Muller with Bayern Munchen
- Cristiano    Ronaldo with Real Madrid

Answer (score -1):

Andry porter scored 357 goals in domestic league

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange! You might want to expand your answer to include more details, e.g. for which club he played.